# Kanji for „Pro“?

Tags: kanji, video-games

What would be the Kanji for „Pro“ (Professional or athlete), in a context like Pro-gamer.

Answer (score 4):

In this context, katakana is used:

プロ

Examples:

[https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/プロ野球選手](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E9%87%8E%E7%90%83%E9%81%B8%E6%89%8B)

[https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/プロゲーマー](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC)